# Importing a Git Project into Aptana with SSH Username and Password

Tags: git, passwords, repository, aptana

I am attempting to setup a git repo for some source code, this is the first time I have used git - but I have made my self familiar with all of the concepts and command line basics which should get me started for now.

I am trying to get Aptana Studio 3 to clone my newly created Git Repo on my development server. What I cannot figure out is how to pass in a Username and Password for the SSH connection. EGit for Eclipse lets me specify a username and password, and seems much more advanced than Aptana's git implementation which only asks me for URI and Path. Which would be @:/path/to/git

I have also found that I cannot for some reason install eGit into Aptana. Its probably missing some dependencies included with Eclipse, but not Aptana (Mylyn is what appears to be having the issues).

I realize that I can use keys, but this is strictly a question of using username and password right now and not am to interested in setting up keyed access.

So in short is there a way to use Aptana Studio 3's Git implementation with a Username and Password for SSH without having to setup RSA Keys for authentication? If there is not in Aptana's Native implementation, is there a way to install a different Git plugin and make it work.

Thanks for your time. 
-Karl

Comment: I have ended up just setting up RSA keys, simple enough - was just hoping to avoid it for the short term.

Comment: Does placing the username into the URI work for you? i.e. username@host:/path/to/repo.git 
It should pick up the username and then prompt for your password if necessary.

Comment: Sure didn't Christoper, I tried a few hundred different combinations. Ok, that's an exaggeration, but it felt like it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Can you file one at http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use eclipse/Aptana, but last year I had a similar "problem" when working with submodules in git via SSH, and maybe the solution I found can work for you.

When you create a submodule in git, the *full* uri of the repository is saved in the `.gitmodules` file, for example: `ssh://myuser@server/paht/to/repo.git`. The problem is that since .gitmodules is under source control, how the rest of the team will access the repository without messing with the .gitmodules?

The solution is simple:

1) I've changed the URL of .gitmodules to `ssh://server/paht/to/repo.git`.
2) I've created a file `~/.ssh/config` with the following content:

```
Host server
  HostName <ip-of-the-server>
  User myuser
```

This way, when git(or openSSH, I guess) tries to connect via ssh, he searchs for a "server" entry in my `~/.ssh/config`, grabs the username from there and only asks me my password.

Maybe this way you can "force" Aptana to do what you want, without resorting to RSA keys.